pg_repack - CREATE INDEX stucj in IDLE state for than 24 hrs
I am in the process of pg_repacking a huge table (13TB). Following is the info for my setup:

pg_total_relation_size (Including indexes) - 13TB
pg_table_size - 4TB
pg_repack version - 1.4.7
Postgres Version - 12.5
Hosted on - AWS Aurora

This is a test setup and there is not traffic on this Aurora cluster since I cloned it from the original cluster.
Started the pg_repack process and it went well initially. I could see queries like the following in ACTIVE state
    INSERT INTO repack.table_1234
    CREATE INDEX
     etc etc

The repacking has been going on for more than 24 hrs now and now I see some CREATE INDEX queries running in IDLE state for more than 10 hrs now and a LOCK TABLE public.table_name IN ACCESS SHARE MODE in Idle in transaction state.
I was thinking that the CREATE INDEX queries will be running in ACTIVE state and not IDLE. These index creation commands have been in IDLE state for long with no progress. When i query the pg_stat_progress_create_index table, I do not get any results.
Can someone tell me if this is the expected behavior? If not, how to repack this table successfully?
Thanks

If the pg_stat_activity line shows that the state is idle, that means that the statement has finished and the server is waiting for the cleint to send the next statement. The query column in pg_stat_activity reports the last statement executed in that session, even after it has stopped being active.
"Running" and "idle" contradict each other.
If your client is still waiting for the server, you may have a client problem or a network problem.

I ran the pg_repack script from a pod and if I do ps aux | grep repack, I can still see the script running in the background. Can you tell me what to do in order to debug this issue? I created a shell script to run repack. The script is very simple - It captures the start time and end time and outputs it after the repack is complete. Should I run repack directly as a command instead? This is the pg_repack command in the script  PGOPTIONS="-c idle_in_transaction_session_timeout=0" pg_repack -h <aurora-endpoint> -U <username> -t <table_name> -k -d <DB-Name> -j 4 --no-kill-backend -E DEBUG

I can't tell you what pg_repack is doing. Use tools like strace to see.
